# Why does Intel XDK generate an '.app' file?

Tags: intel-xdk

I use Intel XDK to build an iOS Legacy App.
But XDK generates a file with an '.app' extension and not an '.ipa' extension.

Where is the problem?
Can you help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596622/how-to-build-a-hybrid-app-with-intel-xdk-for-ios-running-dev-without-owning-an

Answer (score 0):

The legacy build system generates that .APP file. The Cordova build system generates an .IPA file. Please use the Cordova build system, the legacy build system has been deprecated and will be retired in the future.