# Intel XDK - iOS build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm trying to build an iOS app with Intel XDK, but there's some error, and I couldn't understand it, can someone explain it to me, please?

The following build commands failed:

> CompileC
>   build/Stick\'N\'Greet.build/Release-iphoneos/Stick\'N\'Greet.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AdMobPlugin.o
>   Stick\'N\'Greet/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ad-admob/AdMobPlugin.m normal
>   armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1
>   failure) Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,.../builds/build.2017-01-10.20-26-40.y5KXJ3.tmp/cordova_project/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,Stick'N'Greet.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7
>   arm64,-target,Stick'N'Greet,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7
>   arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=.../builds/build.2017-01-10.20-26-40.y5KXJ3.tmp/cordova_project/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=.../builds/build.2017-01-10.20-26-40.y5KXJ3.tmp/cordova_project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Comment: I suppose the idea to use Stick'N'Greet as project name would create troubles related to those chars '. I suggest you to try with StickNGreet instead

Answer (score 0):

Could attached the entire build log up to BUILD FAILED line of the log.

You want to verify your AppID matches your certificate Bundle ID and is specified correctly in the build settings.

Check out my other answer that I provided to build an iOS app which includes a youtube link for an ios build walk through at [How to build a Hybrid App with Intel XDK for iOS running Dev. without owning an Apple Developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596622/how-to-build-a-hybrid-app-with-intel-xdk-for-ios-running-dev-without-owning-an/35659191#35659191)